# If 1 kg of mass is converted to energy and used to accelerate a second 1 kg mass, what would be the final velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, mass-energy

> A bit rusty, tried using $E=mc^2$ to figure out how much kinetic energy would 1kg of mass convert to, and then work backwards to figure out what would be the final velocity of a 1kg mass having kinetic energy equivalent to 1kg mass as kinetic energy.

Not sure how correct this is but here it goes:
$E = 1kg\times c^2$ is the (kinetic) energy equivalent of 1kg mass.
I am hazy about the next step, 1kg mass having kinetic energy of $1kg\times c^2$ w.r.t. to a stationary point would appear to be moving at what (relativistic) speed?  (not sure even if the first step is correct)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a mass $m=1\:\rm kg$ and turn it straight into energy, by whatever means, then indeed you will get an energy $E=mc^2$ (a.k.a. its rest energy) out of it.

If you then use all of that energy to accelerate a second $1\:\rm kg$ mass, that second mass will definitely be accelerated to relativistic domains. This means that you cannot use the old relationship $E_\mathrm{kin}=\frac12 mv^2$ between the particle's velocity $v$ relative to its initial rest frame and its kinetic energy $E_\mathrm{kin}$. Instead, you need to use the relativistic version for the total energy, which reads
$$
E=\gamma mc^2 = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}},
$$
where $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ is known as the Lorentz factor and reduces to $1$ at zero velocity (thereby giving the rest energy $E=mc^2$).

In your case, the second mass already has its rest energy, and you're doubling this, so
$$
E=\gamma mc^2 = 2mc^2,
$$
which then gives you the equation
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}=2$$
that you can solve for $v$ to give $v=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}c\approx 0.8660\,c$.

Comment: I disagree with this answer to some extent. The assumption behind this answer is that all the energy in one mass is used to accelerate a second mass. That is not possible due to the requirement for opposite and equal reaction. In other words, to push something to the right, something has to be pushed against to the left.As an extreme simplification, consider firing a bullet from a rifle. Some of the energy goes to the bullet, and some of the energy pushes the gun back against you.  So even if all the conversions are perfect, probably no more than half of the energy ends up propelling the mass.

Comment: Energy and momentum are independent: while momentum needs to be shared equally, energy doesn't. The share of the energy that ends up propelling the mass can be made arbitrarily big by using a sufficiently large mass ratio between the two masses involved. In other words, if you anchor the shooter to the Earth, it will absorb an equal momentum to the bullet's, while taking on a negligible amount of energy.